# How can i use if statement UItextfield in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, uitextfield

**My code like this**

```
@IBOutlet var variable: UITextField!
var variable2 : String = "magpie";
@IBAction fun c login(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (variable == variable2 ) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
        }
```

I want to do like this but it does not work what can i do ?
if i use

```
if (variable.text! == "a")
```

its working but i dont want to do this. i want to use variable
thank you all

Comment: Your code `if (variable == variable2 )` makes no sense. `variable` is a UITextField, while `variable2` is a String. A UITextField can _never_ equal a String. That is why the compiler won't let you do it.

Comment: So how can i do this ? Cant i compile these two ?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. The only thing you _have_ done, makes no sense. I cannot guess what you might want to do that _does_ make sense. And neither can the compiler.

Comment: What about `if (variable.text! == variable2)`?

Comment: Did you mean `if variable.text == variable2` perhaps...? If so, you have to _say_ it; the compiler can't read your mind.

Comment: For example variable2 = asd and when i write asd in UITextfield i want to go another view controller

Comment: Well that isn't what your question asked, is it?

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
@IBOutlet weak var variable: UITextField!
let variable2 = "magpie"
@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {
    guard variable.text = variable2 else {
       return
    }
    performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
}
```